# Laravel returns "CSRF token mismatch" although CSRF token is included and apprently corrent

Tags: laravel, retrofit2, csrf

I am writing an Android Client built on Retrofit and OkHttp for a web service which is based on Laravel and uses CSRF protection.
Although I send the correct CSRF token (I least I believe so), the web service responds with HTTP status code "419 -  CSRF mismatch".
(Note: 419 is not an official HTTP status code but specific to Laraval).

Where is the error in my second HTTP request? (See below).

More precisely, I try to write an client for Lychee.
Lychees web API is documented [here](https://lycheeorg.github.io/docs/api.html). In the first step, I post a HTTP request to [`php/index.php`](https://lycheeorg.github.io/docs/api.html#phpindexphp-apisessioninit) in order to get the CSRF token.
This first step succeeds.
In the second step, I post a HTTP request to [`/api/Session::login`](https://lycheeorg.github.io/docs/api.html#apisessionlogin).
Although the request header includes the CSRF token, this request fails.
Why?

*The 1st request:*

```
LycheeClient: --> POST https://devel.my-domain.tld/php/index.php
LycheeClient: Content-Length: 0
LycheeClient: Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
LycheeClient: DNT: 1
LycheeClient: Origin: https://devel.my-domain.tld
LycheeClient: --> END POST (0-byte body)
```

*The 1st response:*

```
LycheeClient: <-- 200 https://devel.my-domain.tld/php/index.php (959ms)
LycheeClient: date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 19:03:22 GMT
LycheeClient: server: Apache
LycheeClient: cache-control: no-cache, private
LycheeClient: phpdebugbar-id: X1217d2d3c26dc642b6683c76249c3703
LycheeClient: feature-policy: autoplay 'self'; encrypted-media 'self'; fullscreen 'self'; picture-in-picture *; sync-xhr *
LycheeClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
LycheeClient: x-download-options: noopen
LycheeClient: x-frame-options: deny
LycheeClient: x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
LycheeClient: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
LycheeClient: referrer-policy: no-referrer
LycheeClient: x-clockwork-id: 1617649402-3275-1189279108
LycheeClient: x-clockwork-version: 4.1.8
LycheeClient: set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InRTanVBTmdBenpSMUlFV2hDMkgycnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOU0yY2pKMG5PVTY0SndoWnIzeUVxd0UzbHkrTHUxYzRjazNia3hEdHVqYUhyN1JMRG5nbkJmUFFXZjFWdFpnTzM2Z014bnpPSEYvTUZKdGkzRXM1SlRxSXdVSngwZWNBRUZJNysrOVlid2xocEg0L3BOZlVlNnltWFhNREpjS1EiLCJtYWMiOiJmZmYwZjUxZDlhNWYxZGIxYWM3NGE3MjUyZjY5Y2I0ODFjYWRlZDliZmUxNTZkNGI4NjAzODI3MmVlOTZkMzE3In0%3D; expires=Mon, 05-Apr-2021 21:03:22 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
LycheeClient: set-cookie: lychee_session=eyJpdiI6ImdwYXdTN2x3L0VMRmgwaXNmMG1DbVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZmNXbnNPc1FSQk42aVk3OTJUd1dNSUk0NUJqT1kxT2paWktqZWdKQ21DUFNRcWpuQmx1VUFiYUVYWW5RU2lSSEhMMVZzejFDY3E0S3pLQS9IZDJ0ViswRElQUVJOWVpQRVJUNmM3UDhsY0xQUi9yV3FoSjhseVdHS2kyck9oS0EiLCJtYWMiOiIwNzcxOWEyOGZhMGFlZDE5MzhlM2Q3ZDcwODgwOGMwZWJmYzNkMDQxNmMwOGYzYWU4ZDRhNTljNzViYzYzNTk4In0%3D; expires=Mon, 05-Apr-2021 21:03:22 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
LycheeClient: x-robots-tag: none
LycheeClient: strict-transport-security: max-age=31104000; includeSubDomains
LycheeClient: content-type: application/json
LycheeClient: <-- END HTTP (20941-byte body)
```

*The 2nd request:* (token is included)

```
LycheeClient: --> POST https://devel.my-domain.tld/api/Session::login
LycheeClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
LycheeClient: Content-Length: 37
LycheeClient: Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
LycheeClient: DNT: 1
LycheeClient: Origin: https://devel.my-domain.tld
LycheeClient: X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InRTanVBTmdBenpSMUlFV2hDMkgycnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOU0yY2pKMG5PVTY0SndoWnIzeUVxd0UzbHkrTHUxYzRjazNia3hEdHVqYUhyN1JMRG5nbkJmUFFXZjFWdFpnTzM2Z014bnpPSEYvTUZKdGkzRXM1SlRxSXdVSngwZWNBRUZJNysrOVlid2xocEg0L3BOZlVlNnltWFhNREpjS1EiLCJtYWMiOiJmZmYwZjUxZDlhNWYxZGIxYWM3NGE3MjUyZjY5Y2I0ODFjYWRlZDliZmUxNTZkNGI4NjAzODI3MmVlOTZkMzE3In0
LycheeClient: Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InRTanVBTmdBenpSMUlFV2hDMkgycnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOU0yY2pKMG5PVTY0SndoWnIzeUVxd0UzbHkrTHUxYzRjazNia3hEdHVqYUhyN1JMRG5nbkJmUFFXZjFWdFpnTzM2Z014bnpPSEYvTUZKdGkzRXM1SlRxSXdVSngwZWNBRUZJNysrOVlid2xocEg0L3BOZlVlNnltWFhNREpjS1EiLCJtYWMiOiJmZmYwZjUxZDlhNWYxZGIxYWM3NGE3MjUyZjY5Y2I0ODFjYWRlZDliZmUxNTZkNGI4NjAzODI3MmVlOTZkMzE3In0%3D
LycheeClient: --> END POST (37-byte body)
```

*The 2nd response:*

```
LycheeClient: <-- 419 https://devel.my-domain.tld/api/Session::login (181ms)
LycheeClient: date: Mon, 05 Apr 2021 19:03:23 GMT
LycheeClient: server: Apache
LycheeClient: cache-control: no-cache, private
LycheeClient: phpdebugbar-id: Xfec172b4e199e85ba49731cef5942e7b
LycheeClient: feature-policy: autoplay 'self'; encrypted-media 'self'; fullscreen 'self'; picture-in-picture *; sync-xhr *
LycheeClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
LycheeClient: x-download-options: noopen
LycheeClient: x-frame-options: deny
LycheeClient: x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
LycheeClient: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
LycheeClient: referrer-policy: no-referrer
LycheeClient: x-clockwork-id: 1617649403-0046-418871694
LycheeClient: x-clockwork-version: 4.1.8
LycheeClient: server-timing: app; dur=49.594879150391; desc="Application", db; dur=26.89; desc="Database", timeline-event-total; dur=49.700975418091; desc="Total execution time.", timeline-event-initialisation; dur=5.7110786437988; desc="Application initialisation.", timeline-event-boot; dur=4.6510696411133; desc="Framework booting.", timeline-event-run; dur=43.990135192871; desc="Framework running."
LycheeClient: set-cookie: lychee_session=eyJpdiI6ImZuN1JGZmVTQjBzMzc1RWFtdWFDMFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNE5GdWY3UWFuV3NUZ2VHcEdIUnNnbTNDbXVNa0JZKzJjWGwyd2s4RnArclg3ZUZoU1F3cUwrQ1FLNHlBTzk4SUVpdjZGaVU3Mkt6eEJJOExPeEpRcGJJU3ZpNC9LVy8xQXRQRjd3MVBzQk1CZDM5eXJnY20ySVhXMlRSc24ya1QiLCJtYWMiOiJmZmUyMmMwNWIzYTY0NWMxNTkyNjJlNGM1YzZmOWY2NWM5OTBmOWQxNDAwZTI4YTFlNGIzZTk2MzViNTg3NmE1In0%3D; expires=Mon, 05-Apr-2021 21:03:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
LycheeClient: x-robots-tag: none
LycheeClient: strict-transport-security: max-age=31104000; includeSubDomains
LycheeClient: content-type: application/json
```

*The 2nd response body:*

```
{
  "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
  "file": "/var/www/mhnnet/lychee-dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
  "line": 373,
  "trace": [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: You need to also send the session cookie with the token. I can't see it in your 2nd request

Comment: You are absolute right. I had included the session cooke in a previous test which did not succeeded neither and hence I removed the session cookie to see if anything changes. Of course, the session cookie is necessary. Excuse me, that I posted the wrong output. The true problem is another one. The CSRF token which is sent to the client in a `Set-Cookie`-header ends with `%3D`. If the value of the CSRF token is copied to the `X-XSRF-TOKEN`-header of the next request, this trailing `%3D` must be removed from the value. Why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that one, `%3D` is a urlencoded `=` . I suspect it's because for a cookie you need to urlencode the `=` but for a header you don't so you can replace it with a `=` , however here it seems to work with or without it because the `=` usually indicates padding in a base64 string so may not be strictly necessary

Comment: No, it is not only no necessary, the `%3D` must not be put into the header and it must not be replaced by `=`, it must be removed entirely. If either `%3D` or a `=` is present in the header, Laraval responds with code 419. OK, so it seems that I have to remove the padding when the CSRF token is sent back to the server. Is this documented default behavior?

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't seem like correct behaviour to be honest. XSRF-TOKEN is an encrypted token which includes a verification signature so altering it and sending it back should normally cause the signature validation to fail. Not sure what's going on here